# Can anyone tell my why someone would cast Conjure Minor Elementals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

If I understand this right - you don't pick the CR of the elementals, you pick their maximum CR. You don't pick where it actually appears, it just appears somewhere within 90 feet of you. You don't even pick the element of what you are summoning.

To summarize, you can cast Conjure Minor Elementals at 8th level in an underwater fight, select the option to 3 elementals of CR 2 or lower, and receive 3 CR 1/2 Magma Mephits that are 90 feet away from the fight? In character I would know I am not picking any part of the what I am summoning, I'm basically just yelling help into the void. Why would I waste a 4th level spell to summon a completely random something instead of using something like Polymorph, which just gives you the creature you want and does so by giving something a massive bonus health pool?

Is there any use for this spell besides the tiny benefit of just a couple extra bodies with at most like 40 health - which you can get 5 of with animate objects?

Comment: In what language are you reading your sourcebook? Because I could swear there was something like "you choose" in all summoning spells with multiple options in English version.

Comment: What makes you think they appear in some random location?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: @Molot https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137508/does-conjure-minor-elementals-let-the-caster-choose-which-elemental-to-summon?rq=1

Comment: Are you asking for an in-universe reason, or a mechanical reason?

Comment: Is your GM causing magma mephits to be summoned in an underwater fight deliberately to make your spell less effective? Or is this a hypothetical worse case, because I've found that GMs typically select an option fitting the environment (if they don't let the player choose for themself).

Comment: This question might be improved, and thus eligible for being re-opened, if you focused more on the mechanical benefits of the spell as compared to other conjure X spells or the Animate Objects spell. Also...if what @DavidCoffron suggested is what is happening...this would be better suited as a "How do I talk to my DM about them making my Conjure [X] spells useless by only ever giving me useless minions?"

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/145392/52922

Comment: Hi Ben, and welcome. I've made this post a duplicate of the later one you asked--it seems to me you're grappling with the same unhappiness/disquiet around the class of spells in both posts. If there really are two, separate issues you're having with the class of spells please feel free to [edit] each to make them clearer and flag the posts for review.